# Disable Chromium V70 session restore bubble

Tags: linux, restore, chromium, session

does anybody know how to disable the session restore popup in kiosk mode in the latest Chrome(ium)?

I don't want to use incognito mode, I have tried everything I could find on the Internet, e.g. --noerrdialogs --disable-infobars --disable-session-crashed-bubble --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check --disable-restore-session-state

Neither appear to be working (please note I'm in --kiosk).
Thanks,

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to use incognito mode, which is typically used, for this exact purpose?

Comment: Well honestly no clue - haven't yet measured - what the performance penalty would be to loose every kind of caching - which is brought in by incognito mode.

Answer (score 1):

It appears --app is really what I am looking for. Have tested it, changed exit_type to "Crashed" in Preferences, if I simply display the URL the restore bubble is shown, if I do that via --app it is not

Comment: Can you show the full command line are you using?

Comment: DATADIR=$(realpath ~/.config/chromium/profiles/dev1)

chromium-browser --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream --disable-features=TranslateUI --noerrdialogs --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check --disable-restore-session-state --user-data-dir=$DATADIR --new-window --window-size=1920,1080 --window-position=0,0 --kiosk --app=file://......

I am using a custom profile dir (multiple instances of chromium are running)